# Java collection with generics giving me non-applicable arguments error

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `FourByFourBoard` that extends `GameBoard`. I define the following fields:

```
private Map<Integer,List<Key<? extends GameBoard>>> mGameTypeToKeysMap = new Hashtable<Integer,List<Key<? extends GameBoard>>>();

private List<Key<FourByFourBoard>> mFourByFourBoardKeys = new ArrayList<Key<FourByFourBoard>>();
```

In my constructor, I try to call:

```
mGameTypeToKeysMap.put(Game.FOUR_BY_FOUR, mFourByFourBoardKeys);
```

But I get this:

> The method `put(Integer, List<Key<? extends GameBoard>>)` in the type
>   `Map<Integer,List<Key<? extends GameBoard>>>` is not applicable for the
>   arguments `(int, List<Key<FourByFourBoard>>)`

I can use a different approach to do what I'm trying to do, but after staring at the code for a little while I can't quite figure out why this doesn't work.

**EDIT**

This problem might be simpler than I thought:

If I try:

```
Key<GameBoard> a = mFourByFourBoardKeys.get(0);
```

I get:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Key<FourByFourBoard>` to
>   `Key<GameBoard>`

Even though:

```
GameBoard someBoard = new FourByFourBoard();
```

Is legal. So this is still a generics question, but the collections part was not important. And my head is still spinning a little.

Comment: Key is a class from Objectify, if that helps. http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<A extends B>` and a `List<B>` are not the same, since to the first list you can only add `A` instances, and to the second you can add both `A` and `B` instances.

This is all perfectly well explained in the [Java generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), more specifically on page 4 (Section Generics and Subtyping)

**Edit**

A small example illustrating this and matching your code a bit more closely

```
Map<Integer, List<List<? extends Number>>> a = new Hashtable<Integer,List<List<? extends Number>>>();
List<List<Double>> b = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
a.put(0, b);//won't compile
List<List<? extends Number>> c = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>(  );
a.put( 1, c );//works perfectly
```

The reason why this not compiles is explained in that PDF to which I linked, and to quote the relevant part

> Let’s test our understanding of generics. Is the following code snippet legal?

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(); //1
List<Object> lo = ls; //2
```

> Line 1 is certainly legal. The trickier part of the question is line 2. This boils down
>   to the question: is a List of String a List of Object. Most people’s instinct is to answer:
>   “sure!”.
>   Well, take a look at the next few lines:

```
lo.add(new Object()); // 3
String s = ls.get(0); // 4: attempts to assign an Object to a String
```

I suggest to go through that whole PDF, and take a look at the (other) examples in that document.

Comment: I can do this: private Map<Integer, List<? extends GameBoard>> a = new Hashtable<Integer,List<? extends GameBoard>>(); private List<FourByFourBoard> b = new ArrayList<FourByFourBoard>(); a.put(0, b); -- The problem seems to be that the generic is in the Key.

Comment: Thanks for explaining more thoroughly and quoting that relevant info.

Comment: @robin the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the generic types must match *exactly*. Try this:

```
private List<Key<? extends GameBoard>> mFourByFourBoardKeys = new ArrayList<Key<? extends GameBoard>>();
```

You can still add `FourByFourBoard` instances to the list OK, but the map will accept the list now.

Note: I tested this using standard JDK classes with a similar pattern, so anyone can copy-paste this code for themselves:

```
Map<Integer, List<Comparable<? extends Number>>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Comparable<? extends Number>>>();
List<Comparable<? extends Number>> list = new ArrayList<Comparable<? extends Number>>();
list.add(new Long(0));
map.put(new Integer(1), list);
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` means 'some definite type which i don't know'; `? extends Foo` means 'some definite type which i don't know, but which extends Foo'.

`FourByFourBoard` is a definite type which extends `GameBoard`, but the compiler cannot know that it is the *same* such definite type as the one mentioned in the definition of mGameTypeToKeysMap.

To illustrate, i think it would be allowed to write:

```
mGameTypeToKeysMap = new Hashtable<Integer,List<Key<EightByEightBoard>>>();
```

At which point your attempted `put` would be very wrong.